# TBB: local and global results in parallel_for

Tags: c++, openmp, tbb

I have a question regarding local values in a parallel loop, and updating a global variable.

Example, in pseudo-code: I am searching for a maximum value in a very long vector. I can do it in a loop, like that:

```
int max;
for(i ...) {
    if (max < vector[i]) max = vector[i];
}
```

I can easily parallelize it with OpenMP:

```
int max;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    int local_max;
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(i ...) {
        if (local_max < vector[i]) local_max = vector[i];
    }

#pragma omp critical
    {   
        // choose the best solution from all
        if (max < local_max) max = local_max; local_max
    }
}
```

How can I do the same in TBB `parallel_for`? I don't request an exact code, I would like just to know how to update the global result *at the end of the loop*, not at every iteration...

(I am new to TBB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do in this example is called reduction, so use `parallel_reduce`. It should be more efficient than updating a global variable under a lock. The basic idea is that `local_max` is a member variable of the body class for `parallel_reduce`, and its `join()` method receives another instance of the body and updates `local_max` to be the bigger of the current value and the value in the other instance. Then after the call to parallel_reduce you take the `local_max` value out of the original body object and assign it to the global variable.